# c# regex to extract link after =

Tags: c#, regex, text-extraction

Couldn't find better title but i need a Regex to extract link from sample below.

```
snip...  flashvars.image_url = 'http://domain.com/test.jpg' ..snip
```

assuming regex is the best way.

thanks

Comment: I've edited the question to reflect what I think was the intent. Apologies in advance if I got it wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following sample code.  It shows how one might extract from your supplied string.  But I have expanded upon the string some.  Generally, the use of .* is too all inclusive (as the example below demonstrates).

The main point, is there are several ways to do what you are asking, the first answer given uses "look-around" while the second suggests the "Groups" approach.  The choice mainly depend upon your actual data.

```
        string[] tests = {
                @"snip...  flashvars.image_url = 'http://domain.com/test.jpg' ..snip",
                @"snip...  flashvars.image_url = 'http://domain.com/test.jpg' flashvars2.image_url = 'http://someother.domain.com/test.jpg'",
        };
        string[] patterns = {
                @"(?<==\s')[^']*(?=')",
                @"=\s*'(.*)'",
                @"=\s*'([^']*)'",
                             };
        foreach (string pattern in patterns)
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            foreach (string test in tests)
                foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(test, pattern))
                {
                    if (m.Groups.Count > 1)
                        Console.WriteLine("{0}", m.Groups[1].Value);
                    else
                        Console.WriteLine("{0}", m.Value);
                }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: New regex matching your edited question:

You need to match what's between quotes, after a `=`, right?

```
@"(?<==\s*')[^']*(?=')"
```

should do.

`(?<==\s*')` asserts that there is a `=`, optionally followed by whitespace, followed by a `'`, just before our current position (positive lookbehind).

`[^']*` matches any number of non-`'` characters.

`(?=')` asserts that the match stops before the next `'`.

This regex doesn't check if there is indeed a URL inside those quotes. If you want to do that, use

```
@"(?<==\s*')(?=(?:https?|ftp|mailto)\b)[^']*(?=')"
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple regex for this would be `@"=\s*'(.*)'"`.